# Python SQLite Return Default String For Non-Existent Row

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a DB with ID/Topic/Definition columns. When a select query is made, with possibly hundreds of parameters, I would like the fetchall call to also return  the topic of any non-existent rows with a default text (i.e. "Not Found").

I realize this could be done in a loop, but that would query the DB every cycle and have a significant performance hit. With the parameters joined by "OR" in a single select statement the search is nearly instantaneous.

Is there a way to get a return of the query (topic) with default text for non-existent rows in SQLite?

Table Structure (named "dictionary")

```
ID|Topic|Definition   
1|wd1|def1
2|wd3|def3
```

Sample Query

```
SELECT Topic,Definition FROM dictionary WHERE Topic = "wd1" or Topic = "wd2" or topic = "wd3"'
```

Desired Return

```
[(wd1, def1), (wd2, "Not Found"), (wd3, def3)]
```

Comment: @CL, I added the table structure, sample query, and desired return. It is very simple and basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data like `wd2` out of a query, such data must be in the database in the first place.
You could put it into a temporary table, or use a [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html).

To include rows without a match, use an [outer join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join):

```sql
WITH IDs(ID) AS ( VALUES ('wd1'), ('wd2'), ('wd3') )
SELECT Topic,
       IFNULL(Definition, 'Not Found') AS Definition
FROM IDs
LEFT JOIN dictionary USING (ID);
```